# array of structs as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I am trying to pass a pointer to an array of `struct`s as a template argument. I managed to do it after a while:

```
struct something{};

constexpr const something single;
constexpr const something array[12];
template<const something* arg> void f() {}

template<typename T>
constexpr T* workaround(T* v){
    return v;
};

void bind(){
    f<&single>();                       //OK
    f<array>();                         //NO
    f<&array>();                        //NO
    f<&array[0]>();                     //NO
    f<workaround(array)>();             //NO
    f<(const something*)array>();       //OK
}
```

Is this one of the rare cases where an array cannot be transparently used as a pointer, or is it a compiler bug?

Comment: Have you tried pointers to arrays?

Comment: FWIW, Apple clang v4.1 (clang v3.1) won't compile most of this. For starters, it rejects default initialization of `single` and `array` because `something` doesn't have a user-defined default constructor. And when I altered it so they are initialized (i.e `constexpr const Elem single {}`) it rejects ALL of your variations of calling `f` reporting: "candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'arg'"

Answer (score 1):

I actually believe the simplest form of the call, `f<array>();`, does work if only you declare-define `array` correctly:

```
struct Elem
{ };

constexpr const Elem array[5] { {} , {} , {} , {} , {} };

template<const Elem* arg> void f()
{ }

int main()
{
  f<array>();
  return 0;
}
```

The only thing I changed (apart from reducing the array from 12 to 5 elements) is to add an initializer for `array`.

(This compiles for me, using GCC 4.7.2.)

Comment: why does initialization matter here?

Comment: @LorenzoPistone Since `array` is a constant expression, the compiler needs its definition when evaluating the template. The definition is provided by the initialization. The missing initialization was the only thing GCC seemed to be confused about.

Comment: but then `f<(const something*)array>()` shouldn't have worked.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone True. And actually, my previous comment is not quite logical. The actual values of the array entries (provided by initialization) shouldn't be necessary. I can't explain why it's important to GCC, but then, I wonder how are you ever going to assign values to the `constexpr` array of `const` objects, if not by initialization?

Answer (score 1):

Fooling around with this with Apple clang v4.1, I've arrived at the below code which compiles. I have to admit I don't know if it's correct of Clang to insist on external linkage for `single` and `array`. Also, based it on jogojapan's modifications for no particular reason.

```
struct Elem {};

extern const Elem single;
extern const Elem array[3];

constexpr const Elem single {};
constexpr const Elem array[3] {{},{},{}};

template<const Elem* arg> void f()
{ }

int main()
{
    f<&single>();
    f<array>();
    return 0;
}
```

FWIW, I arrived at this shot in the dark after stumbling across this:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2006/Jun/msg00799.html